# Using obj file format for directx 11

Tags: c++, direct3d, directx-11, wavefront

Having the components of an obj file (the separated values for the texture, normal and vertex having their own index). Is it possible to send the texture, vertex and normal values to the buffer separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct3D doesn't directly support independently indexed vertex components. You can set up a vertex buffer containing just the indices from the .obj file and look the individual components up yourself from a StructuredBuffer in your vertex shader though.